# Window (Tkinter) in another file shows up whenever the main script is executed

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day everyone. I've been baffled dealing with my python code. Im using Tkinter for my GUI for our individual school project.

I have this code as a window (for my *Create* menu in menu bar in main.py) on another file (let's say functions.py):

```
def createNew(coord):
    #create a new window element
    createWindow = tk.Tk()
    createWindow.title("Create a new tracker")
    createWindow.geometry("350x400")

    createWindow.focus_force()
    createWindow.grab_set()

    x = coord[0]
    y = coord[1]

    createWindow.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 250, y + 200))
```

The above code has that `coord` argument which receives the input from main.py with this code (the functions.py is imported as funct):

```
parentPosition = [window.winfo_x(), window.winfo_y()]
...
menubar = tk.Menu(window)
#file menu
file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label='Create new tracker', command=funct.createNew(parentPosition))
```

My problem is that whenever I execute the main.py, this window from functions.py automatically shows up even though I didn't select the *Create* menu from main.py. The intended location is correct anyway.

[Actual snapshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEeDh.png)

What is the issue within my code? Any insights would be appreciated.

PS. I intentionally put the function createNew in functions.py rathen than on main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute the function immediately when you run the line

```py
file.add_command(label='Create new tracker', command=funct.createNew(parentPosition))
```

This is because, by putting a pair of brackets after the function name, you call it right away, and pass its return value to the `add_command` function.

In order to get around this, you can use the `lambda` keyword to delay execution of the function until it is called again:

```py
file.add_command(label='Create new tracker', command=lambda: funct.createNew(parentPosition))
```

You can find out more about lambda functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).